# RTMP/Stream player with seekable buffer

Tags: video, media-player, streaming

I currently watch streams with VLC Media Player but I miss one feature which is a seekable buffer.

EyeTV has such a feature called "Live Buffer". It enables you to pause, seek or instant replay the material in the buffer whose size you can define up into the gigabytes. You also can at any time jump back to "live" which is the end of the buffer.

Is there an application which can do the same thing for RTMP/HTTP streams?

**Requirements:**

- Seekable buffer (minimum the ability to "instant replay" the last minute)
- RTMP and optionally HTTP support
- any platform (but OS X preferred)
- free or paid

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a problem you can fix from the player side.  Some content Delivery Networks (CDNs) such as Edgecast and Akamai have configuration settings in their streaming platforms that provide the ability to scroll back live video streams. But that's not done in the player.

Most simple players only buffer enough video to avoid stalls and sputters.  This buffering is a major contribution to "stream delay" (latency) that many find an annoying attribute of streamed live video.